# mysql join query taking too many resources

Tags: mysql, join, debian, left-join

I am using python2.7 and mysql5.5 on debian.

With this query mysql use 100% cpu:

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+-----+------------------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User             | Host            | db      | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-----+------------------+-----------------+---------+---------+------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 253 | whitewall        | localhost:39377 | mailing | Query   |    4 | Sending data | 
SELECT
    contacts.ID,
    contacts.RATING,
    mails.MANDRILL_ID
FROM contacts
    LEFT JOIN mails
        ON mails.CONTACT_ID = contacts.ID
HAVING mails.MANDRILL_ID = 'fea4b3b036b44655a7e24121ac359d0a' |
```

Any hints on what could be going wrong?

Comment: I don't see a query, just some random lines of code.

Comment: Where is your agregating function? (and the rest of a query, tbh)

Comment: How is it a Python related question exactly ?

Comment: Sorry if its not well easked, its my first time asking on stackoverflow. I hope the output from mysql client helps understand the problem

Comment: Try changing `having` into `where` for starters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct way to write the query:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.RATING, c.MANDRILL_ID
FROM contacts c JOIN
     mails m
     ON m.CONTACT_ID = c.ID
WHERE m.MANDRILL_ID = 'fea4b3b036b44655a7e24121ac359d0a';
```

For performance, you want the following indexes:  `mails(mandrill_id, contact_id)` and `contacts(id)` (you probably have the latter).

Notes:

- The `left join` was being turned into a `join` anyway by the condition on `mails`.
- The `having` clause should really be used primarily with `group by`.  MySQL has an extension, but you don't need it.  Use `where`.
- The use of `having` probably prevented the optimizer from choosing the best optimization path.
- Table aliases make queries easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

Change `HAVING` to `WHERE`.

Your query is, according to this process list, delivering a result set to your client (your python program).  It's rare to see a query in this state unless the result set is very large indeed.

Your query, as written, returns every row in your `contacts` table to your python program.  If you want to return only the `contacts` row that's related to the `mails` row with `MANDRILL_ID = 'fea4b3b036b44655a7e24121ac359d0a'` change your `LEFT JOIN` to a `JOIN`.